# Get all subdirectories matching a name

Tags: java, fileutils

I am trying to get all subdirectories that have "messages_" in the name using FileUtils

```
Collection<File> filesToRead = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(fromDirectory),
        new DirectoryFileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if (dir.isDirectory() && dir.getName().contains("messages_")){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

This is not working for me. How to achieve this using FileUtils?

Comment: What are you getting as output?

Comment: @svasa: I am getting an empty list. Forgot to mention the subdirectories are not immediate children of the `fromDirectory`

Comment: Did you try DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY instead of TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collection<File> filesToRead = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File(fromDirectory),
        FalseFileFilter.INSTANCE, // exclude files
        new WildcardFileFilter("*messages_*") // folders filter
);
```